# Sorting CoreData in reverse chronological order with NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have a Core Data database set up with a tableview and I'm trying to set it up where the the objects displayed in the table view are displayed in reverse chronological order. I'm trying to do this with NSSortDescriptor but can't figure out how to order it in reverse chronological order. Any ideas? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
func getCoreData(){

        var appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var req : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "KeptQuotes")

        var s = NSSortDescriptor(key: "quote", ascending: true)
        req.sortDescriptors = [s]

        var error : NSError?

        let fetchedResults = context.executeFetchRequest(req, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?


        if let results = fetchedResults {

            keptQuotes = results

        }else{

            println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")

        }

        tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setup a date attribute in your entity of type NSDate, then set this attribute as your sort descriptor and set ascending to false.

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without setting the date?

Comment: You have to provide it with some attribute to sort by and it seems like a date attribute would fit the data that you're handling

Comment: Aha, what would happen to objects that don't have the date object added to it - would they be left out of the table view or just sent to the back?

Comment: Not sure how it would handle that, but there's no harm in trying it anyways. And worst case scenario you can write your own comparison method

Comment: "You construct an instance of NSSortDescriptor by specifying the key path of the property to be compared, the order of the sort (ascending or descending), and (optionally) a selector to use to perform the comparison"